# get_post_meta - WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging

This code is designed to add a button to specific posts using the `get_post_meta` function. How do I alter the `get_post_meta` function to display this button on a specific post? I have already tried changing its `$post->ID` parameter to '1464', which is the post ID I want to use.

```
function custom_listify_single_job_listing_actions_after() {
    global $post;

    $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_custom_meta_key', true );

    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" class="button">My Button</a>';
}
add_filter( 'listify_single_job_listing_actions_after', 'custom_listify_single_job_listing_actions_after' );
```

Comment: ask here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Cross posted here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/225967/46066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to run this code on a specific post, you need to add an `if` statement to check for that post ID.

Your code would need to look similar to this:

```
if($post->ID == 1464){
    $url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_custom_meta_key', true );

    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $url ) . '" class="button">My Button</a>';
}
```

This simply wraps the `get_post_meta()` function and `echo` statement so that *both* of these only run on the post you want them to. Any other post will ignore the code.